# Why is my iOS app taking a long time to load on my device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an app, so far basic on technical grounds, that seems to take a long time to load. At present it displays a background image and shows 1-2 images on top of it, not much more sophisticated than a "Hello, World!" app.

The status in Xcode is "Waiting for ____________: ____________'s iPhone to launch", and it stays there for several minutes before finally waiting for it to launch. This is with the device tethered to the computer. Xcode says, "No issues" to the right of that.

The only thing I can think of that may need slimming down is several high-resolution images. I'm not doing anything particularly interesting besides displaying a shrunken version of one of them, and in the past I had what seemed like normal response times.

Are there any obvious causes for why a starter app should take several minutes to get up and running on an iPhone?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it take long time to start when you launch it on device directly, not through Xcode?

Comment: It hasn't opened the iOS simulator through XCode, but it loads (slowly) if I try to start it from the simulator, wait for a fresh app to load (perhaps after deleting the previous run's app), and open the app from my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would account for "several minutes" but the time between compilation finishing and the app launching includes time to copy the app to the device, for the device to verify the code signature, and then for the debug server to launch, read in your whole app and start communicating with Xcode. In a large application with a lot of image resources, the time required to do these things can be quite noticeable (read: annoying as all get out.) None of those tasks needs to be done when simply launching a pre-existing, previously launched application, without a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 iPhones and one of them is behaving the same as yours. The only difference is that the "slow" one has 350 or so apps installed and the fast one is almost clean. I think this is the problem in my case. You can just reset all contents (no apps installed) just to check if it solves the problem in your case.